# How to make Tkinter Checkbutton flash

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Python 2.7 on Mac OSX Sierra
Tkinter 8.5

I'm following along this [Tkinter documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) and trying out different widgets, but having some difficulty making a checkbutton flash with the results described in the docs.

I've got "self.newButton" properly calling the "makeCheckbuttonFlash" and printing the message, but not seeing any change to the checkbutton.

**Note: In the below code, I've lost formatting on the tabs for the methods - not sure how to fix**

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Server(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master = None):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

    self.grid(sticky = tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
    self.createWidgets()

def createWidgets(self):

    top = self.winfo_toplevel()

    top.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    top.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Quit", command = self.quit)

    self.quitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.S)

    self.newButton = tk.Button(self, text = "New", command = self.makeCheckButtonFlash)

    self.newButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.N + tk.S)

    self.checkButton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Check Button", activeforeground = "red") 

    self.checkButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

def makeCheckButtonFlash(self):
    print "makeCheckButtonFlash"
    self.checkButton.flash()

app = Server()

app.master.title("Server")

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can fix the tab problem by using spaces rather than tabs. Please take the time to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own flash function if Mac doesn't implement the flash function as well as you like. Then you can also control all of the parameters like 2 or more colors to flash, time delay between flashes, how many times to flash, etc. Here is a modification of your makeCheckButtonFlash to do some of these things.

```
def makeCheckButtonFlash(self, color='black', times=5):
    if self.checkButton['foreground'] == self.checkButton['activeforeground']:
        self.checkButton['foreground'] = color
    else:
        self.checkButton['foreground'] = self.checkButton['activeforeground']
    times -= 1
    if times:
        self.checkButton.after(100, lambda t=times: self.makeCheckButtonFlash(times=t))
    else:
        self.checkButton['foreground'] = color
```